# carbon format date time with am to database datatime format

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I'am using Laravel and bootstrap Date time picker
the picker return to me a sting like this

> "16/12/2017 16:53 PM"

I wanna store it in database in date time format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better chaging for the format in your js so it's only a date time.

Having said that this will work:

```
//date
$date = "16/12/2017 16:53 PM";

//replace / with -
$date = str_replace('/','-',$date);

//remove PM and AM

$date = str_replace('PM','',$date);
$date = str_replace('AM','',$date);

//create a new instance of DateTime and pass in the date
$date = new \DateTime($date);

//print date format
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$dateTime = new Carbon\Carbon('2017-01-23 3:45pm');
```

Alternatively, if you have a specific format:

```
$dateTime = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y g:ia', '05/21/1975 3:59am');
```